# How to correctly set writable the /var/www/ directory of an Ubuntu Linux system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, chmod

I am a software developer so I am not so into operating system configuration details and I have the following problem.

I have installed a **LAMP** environment of an **Ubuntu Linux** system dedicated to the develop (it is on my PC and it is not a production server).

So I am trying to set the **/var/www** as the workspace of Aptana (the IDE that I use for PHP develop) but I can't do it because I have not the permission to write in this directory (I think that it is my logged user that have not this permission).

So I know that probably I can solve this issue simply changing this permission by:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/
```

I think that it makes readable, writable and executable anything that it is into the **/var/www/** directory, is it right? But for who? For every user that can be registered on my system or only for the logged user?

Reading online it seems to me that (maybe, I am absolutly not sure) I can obtain the same result (write into the **/var/www/** directory) by doing something like:

```
sudo chown -R myUserName:www-data /var/www/
sudo chmod -R g+s /var/www/
```

Is these 2 commands true for my pourpose? What exactly does? I am trying to read the official documentation and it seems to me that works in this way:

1. First I set my user as the owner of the **/var/www/** directory (so it means that it can write into this directory and in all subdirectories because use the -R parm?) and assigns the **www-data** group. But what is this **www-data** group? Is it a standard Linux group or is a new group that simply can group member?
2. I really have no idea about what exactly does the second statment. What it does?

What solution are better?

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on: http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: Usually a programmer prefers to have a development environment as close as possible to the final one. I **did not** suggest you to set `www` with `chmod 777`. You can read many other reason to avoid it [e.g. from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically the first command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/
```

Makes it readable, writable and executable by anyone (any user).
You are on the right track with the latter commands, as you can set `chown` to `www-data`. `www-data` is a default user/group for Apache.

Or you could create a new group and add yourself and www-data there, then assign the group to the folder permission with `chown`.

Also instead of using numeric chmod values, you can use `chmod -R ugo+rwx folder` which means that give user, group and others => read, write and execute rights to this folder. Similar way you can also remove rights `chmod -R ugo-rwx folder`.

Setting directory with `g+s` makes all new files created in said directory have their group set to the directory's group.